# Security tips for adding wireless AP to domain network?

Tags: networking, wifi

I am researching best-practices for adding wireless to our existing domain network. My DHCP server is running Windows Server 03 Standard (not sure if thats useful). I am familiar with simple home networking but I thought I'd get some expert advice for the more advanced stuff. Any tips and / or best-practices?

Is this [Cisco Wireless Access Point](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833150042) a good option? Are there any additional hardware recommendations?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Not programming-related.

Comment: Wasn't aware the editing procedure changed; i will use the options in "close question" from now on! Thanks!

Comment: The OP is asking about home networking, so on balance I'd say this belongs here.

Comment: @Joe Koberg - it's just that the redundant tag gets left on the original question.

Comment: @ChrisF: disagree.  he says he's *familiar* with home networking; not the same thing.  i'd assume this is for a small business, but without further details we really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [Cisco 1100 series](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833120034&cm_re=cisco_WAP-_-33-120-034-_-Product) much better. Dual band. Multiple SSIDs per radio. Manageable with IOS interface.

And it comes with ceiling grid mounts!

Server OS or DHCP should not matter.

A best practice is to [setup RADIUS and have the AP authenticate against that](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6148579.html) with the user's domain password, instead of using a static passoword that "everyone knows".

Comment: Old answer but new question: Is it possible to "tie" several 1110 together into a big SSID? I need to deploy wireless across two floors (with armored concrete between), so I'll need 2 bases on each flor.

Comment: Yes. Most people don't know that "all you have to do" is have the same SSID and password on multiple APs and the client will "just work".

The Ciscos can also use a cisco-proprietary method to exchange wireless domain management information with each other.

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a home network I would shy away from Cisco as its certainly overkill, high cost, and more time consuming to manage than a high end home router. If this is for a SOHO implementation I might still recommend a high end home router. But if you are going to need multiple APs for coverage and such then sure Cisco is the way to go.

Again, depending on your situation, the answer to your question changes. The bigger the implementation the more time and money you can spend on security. If this is a small implementation you can probably get away with AES and WPA2. The bigger you get you may want to look into WPA2 Enterprise with Certificates and a certificate server and possibly EAP-TLS. But unless you have a multi-floor office or medium size office needing 5-10 APs, I wouldn't even worry about LWAPP or CAPWAP.

If my answer sounds vague and generic it is because I know nothing about your implementation. If you would like more specifics than just reply back with more information.